# Create a 64 bit dll from a 32 bit C dll

Tags: windows, dll, 32bit-64bit

I have a 32-bit dll that I have gotten from a third party. They have no 64 bit version. I wish to load this dll into 64 bit python. To do this, I need a 64 bit dll. Is there a tool to convert a 32 bit dll to a 64 bit dll or is this impossible? If it impossible then I must use 32 bit python I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the vendor can do this, unless you get access to the DLL's source code. It must be recompiled for 64 bit.

I guess you'll have to use 32-bit python...

Answer (score 1):

32 and 64bit DLLS have different [ABIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions). You just can't load a 32bit DLL into a 64bit process or the other way around.

As mentioned in the comments, you have to recompile from source.

Comment: I understand that, but can I create a 64 bit dll from a 32 bit dll.

Comment: The issue is not ABI or calling convention. The issue is that a single process cannot mix modules of both 32 and 64 bits

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a 64-bit DLL from 32-bit one without the source code.

But you can create an adapter as a native 32-bit application that loads the 32-bit DLL and provides access to it's functions via some kind of inter-process communications (e.g. named pipes)

Of course, that's may be senseless in some cases and you may prefer to use 32-bit python.
So it depends.